# Cannot call methods on IBOutlets inside initWithCoder: method

Tags: objective-c, iboutlet

I have a class that sets `keyboard` as its input view

```
NSArray *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FormulaKeyboard" owner:self options:nil];

for (id object in bundle) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[FormulaKeyboard class]])
        keyboard = (FormulaKeyboard *)object;
}
```

In the init method of the keyboard class (subclass of NSObject), I try to set the title text of several UIButtons that are created using the nib.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {

    NSArray *keyboardElements =  [delegate provideKeyElements];
    [element1 setTitle:[keyboardElements objectAtIndex:0]  forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [element2 setTitle:[keyboardElements objectAtIndex:1]  forState: UIControlStateNormal]; 
    [element3 setTitle:[keyboardElements objectAtIndex:2]  forState: UIControlStateNormal]; 
    [element4 setTitle:[keyboardElements objectAtIndex:3]  forState: UIControlStateNormal]; 
    [element5 setTitle:[keyboardElements objectAtIndex:4]  forState: UIControlStateNormal]; 

    }
    return self;
}
```

However, the buttons do not receive the message. When I implement the code into another method, the setTitle: methods work fine, but I would like the methods to be called as soon as the keyboard is created. I have verified using NSLog that the initWithCoder: method is called. I have also tried putting the code into the awakeFromNib method, but that does not work either.

Comment: Where is the keyboard's delegate being set?

Comment: Have you logged keyboardElements and element1 to see if they're not nil?

Comment: the keyboard's delegate is the viewcontroller that holds the view creating the keyboard

Comment: keyboardElements and element1 are both nil in the int method, strangely.

however, neither are nil if I put the code in another method

Comment: I think that initWithCoder is just too early in the process. Is there some reason you don't do it in the view controller's viewWillAppearMethod (is this iOS)?

Comment: I just felt that init would be most convenient. I could still add the code elsewhere. Thanks

Comment: Please confirm: did you implement `awakeFromNib:` (with colon, as you wrote) or `awakeFromNib` (without)?  The correct version is the one without a colon, and it does matter.